# Is it possible to preload standalone components in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I am studying Angular for the first time and I saw that from version 15, standalone components were introduced. I know that it is possible to apply lazy loading with loadComponent and import, but can preloading be applied?
`{path: 'pesquisa', loadComponent: () => import('./componentes/pesquisa/pesquisa.component').then(m => m.PesquisaComponent), data: {preload: true}}`

Would this be enough? How do I test if it is really being preloaded?"

Comment: Check the network tab in the inspector

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to either preload all the lazy loading routes or implement a custom preloading strategy to selectively preload specific routes.

To preload all the lazy loading routes:
add `withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)` in `app.config.ts`

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules))]
};
```

For custom preloading strategy please refer [this blog](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/optimize-your-angular-apps-user-experience-with-preloading-strategies-3ie7)

Please refer to the following links for detailed explanations and examples.

1. [Explains preloading](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/optimize-your-angular-apps-user-experience-with-preloading-strategies-3ie7)
2. [Provides examples for both NgModule and Standalone Components.](https://angularsnippets.dev/snippets/preloading-strategy/)